# GLSL precision in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a texture declared as follows:

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA16F, win.width, win.height, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

I want to dump z-buffer values in color channels,
I do it with the following fragment shader:

```
#version 330
precision highp float;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color_out;

void main()
{
float z = gl_FragCoord.z;
color_out = vec4(z,z,z, 0); 
}
```

Unfortunately I have a high loss of precision between Z buffer values I read with glreadpixel and ones i get dumped into my texture color channels, any idea why ?

here are the values I expect:

```
depth value 0.996680 : at pixel 274300 
depth value 0.996690 : at pixel 274301 
depth value 0.996701 : at pixel 274302 
depth value 0.996712 : at pixel 274303 
depth value 0.996722 : at pixel 274304 
depth value 0.996733 : at pixel 274305 
depth value 0.996743 : at pixel 274306
```

here is what I get:

```
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274300 
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274301 
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274302 
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274303 
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274304 
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274305 
color 0.996078 : at pixel 274306
```

Comment: 'GL_RGBA16F' - is this 16 bit per pixel, like 4 bits per channel? Or is it 16 bit per channel and 64 bits per pixel?

Comment: Really good question, I did not found anything about this but I assume it's 16 bit per channel. Changing GL_RGBA16F to GL_RGBA32F doesn't make any precision difference

Comment: GL_RGBA16F means 16bit per channel. Have a look [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) for a table with all formats and sizes

Comment: wow I'm stupid thanks for the tip, so as it's 16 bit per channel do you know why I still lose precision with GL_RGBA32F ?

Comment: @ThomasKostas: Can you elaborate on what "I still lose precision" exactly means? What values are you expecting, and what are you observing?

Comment: @derhass I edited my post :)

Comment: @ThomasKostas: Those values look exactly like 8 bit normalized UINT format (254/255). Are you sure the you really rendering to the correct texture?

Comment: you highlight a good point that was my mistake...